# php decoded utf values not displaying on google chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, encoding, utf

i have following code when i run this code on firefox its works fine giving out put as i want when i run this code on Google chrome out put not correct showing any idea?

```
<?php

$encode=utf8_encode("වවවවවවවවවවව");

$decode=utf8_decode($encode);

print_r($decode);

die;

?>
```

thanks in advance
roshan

Comment: Are these steps necessary? Why not just put "වවවවවවවවවවව" in an HTML page?

Comment: Are you defining your charset as utf-8 in your <head>?

Comment: yes karnage that was the issue thank you very much for the reply!!!

Comment: @deceze  yes friend these steps are necessary this just a example only thanks for reply cheers

Comment: @Roshan these steps are  definitely not necessary; they may even be harmful. If a browser still displays it correctly, it's just because it's *very* lenient. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @ Pekka this just a example and problem was solved thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well move this to answer section:

Define UTF-8 as your charset in your `<head>`

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 3):

This code makes no sense. [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/utf8_encode) is a function to convert ISO-8859-1 data into UTF-8.

Googling shows that your data is a [singhalese character](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/unicode/?block=0D80-0DFF), which isn't part of ISO-8859-1. It is extremely likely that it will be destroyed in the first `utf8_encode()` call.

I guess the answer in this specific situation is, don't use `utf8_encode()`. If that doesn't work for you, please provide some more context about what you are doing. Maybe you are looking for [`iconv()`](http://php.net/iconv)?

Comment: @ Pekka this just a example and problem was solved thanks for the reply

Comment: @Roshan that it happens to work in a browser doesn't always mean that the problem is really *solved*. When dealing with encoding stuff, it's much better to understand what is actually happening. But it's your call